# Проблемы с кодировкой в Spring MVC при сохранении в базу данных MySQL на сервере

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, кодировка, vps

Написал небольшое приложение на Spring MVC где пользователи могут вносить свои данные в БД. При запуске локально все нормально отображается, а при запуске на VPS те данные, которые вносятся контроллером в базу отображаются как (?????? ?? ????).

добавил В pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        .....
    </properties>
```

В web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

В appconfig-mvc.xml:

```
<beans:bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:array>
                <beans:bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:array>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    .......
```

Пробовал при создании базы на сервере писать

> CREATE DATABASE mydb
>   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
>   DEFAULT COLLATE
>   utf8_general_ci;

Все равно в базе вопросы (когда делаю SELECT из базы - там тоже вопросы на месте русского текста).

РЕДАКТИРОВАНО:
на JSP странице откуда происходит сохранение также стоит:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

подключение к БД:

```
<util:properties id="application" location="classpath:database.properties"/>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="#{application.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="#{application.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="#{application.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="#{application.password}" />

        <beans:property name="maxIdle" value="-1"/>
        <beans:property name="maxActive" value="-1"/>
        <beans:property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="-1"/>
        <beans:property name="maxWait" value="20000"/>
        <beans:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <beans:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: `characterEncoding` при подключении к БД стоит? Добавьте конфиг как подключаетесь к БД

Comment: добавил данные из appconfig-data.xml

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к конфигу `<beans:property name="characterEncoding" value="utf8" />`

Comment: invalid property

Comment: тогда попробуйте указать url для подключения к БД вроде этого: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: а название БД не нужно указывать?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, решение нашел отредактировав файл настроек mysql на сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за предложенные варианты! Решение нашел [здесь](http://hosting-vds-vps.ru/hosting/mysql.html). Делаем все как там написано в последнем пункте и все работает. Видимо кодировка по умолчанию при установке MySQL на Ubuntu ставится не с поддержкой русского языка. Правда при вставке данных в базу вручную текст отображается иероглифами. Но это совсем другая история (зачем его вставлять вручную?).

Если коротко, допустим, мы будем заменять кодировку на cp1251, то в конфигурационном файле my.cnf, который находится в каталоге /etc/mysql/my.cnf, ищем модуль [mysqld] и меняем его на:

```
[mysqld]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_set_client=cp1251
character_set_server=cp1251
```

Делаем рестарт MySQL (перезагрузку необходимо делать всегда после внесения каких-либо изменений):  service mysql restart.
Пишем русскими буквами что нам нужно)

Comment: напишите более развернуто, чтоб можно было решить вопрос без перехода по ссылке

Comment: @MrFylypenko написал)